# Avoid duplication in a join (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have to join 2 tables.

I have to found the parameter Value in the table 2 to add this to my table 1.
But this is a historical table, so is in the form:

```
object  value   date 
1       232     24/10/2020    
1       111     11/06/2019          
2       231     22/09/2011 
2       545     05/09/2020
...     ...     ...
```

How I can write the join query to avoid duplication and take only the value for the last date?

I have tried some like:

```
select a.*, b.value
from tableA a, (select value, object max(date) from tableB group by object, value)b
where a.object = b.oject
```

But is wrong

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to generate a sequential number and then choose the first one:

```
select a.*, b.value
from tableA a join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by object order by date desc) as seqnum
      from tableB
     ) b
     on a.object = b.object and seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: This is missing a filter condition as you never do anything with `seqnum`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need from the second table can be done in a single aggregate subquery:

```
select a.*, b.value
from   tableA a
       join (
              select object, 
                     max(value) keep (dense_rank last order by date_col) as value
              from   tableB
              group  by object
            ) b
       on a.object = b.object
;
```

If in `tableB` there may be duplicates by `(object, date_col)` then it is possible that "the most recent value" is ambiguous (the "most recent date" may appear more than once). The query will select the highest of the "most recent values"; you can change that as needed (if this is even a possible problem to begin with). Also, if the `date_col` may be null, you may need to add `nulls first` after `order by date_col` in the aggregate function.

I wrote `date_col` as `date` is a reserved keyword, so it can't be a column name. Perhaps the same is true of "object". I hope you don't actually have columns named OBJECT and DATE, do you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to filter out unnecessary records as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT A.*,
           B.VALUE,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.OBJECT ORDER BY B.DATE DESC NULLS LAST) AS RN
      FROM TABLEA   A
      JOIN TABLEB   B ON A.OBJECT = B.OJECT
) WHERE RN = 1
```